# Gmail - Security - What happened to the option / button that would GENERATE an "Email-Account-Monthly-Activity-Report" for the month?

Tags: gmail

**THE QUESTION**
Gmail - Security - What happened to the option / button that would generate an "**Email-Account-Monthly-Activity-Report**" for the month, **which would show how many emails you received in that month** and other information ?

**REASON FOR ASKING THIS QUESTION**
Someone always gets my new Gmail password, deletes new emails before I see my inbox, and assumedly logs in at same time I do.

**DETAILS**

- So, obviously if I had the generate the "**Email-Account-Monthly-Activity-Report**" **feature that used to exist**, for the month, **which used to show how many emails you received in that month** and other information, I would be able to confirm / determine if any emails have been deleted by another person.
- **A Further Question Would Be** - When I sign-out of Gmail does it also sign me out of **all other sessions**, or is there a separate button somewhere to simply sign-out of all other sessions by just clicking one single button ?
- I also alternatively think, that **they** always sign-in at the exact same time I do, so that when I check the "Last account activity" link I will not see their sign-in.
- I **'almost'** always receive the message "there may be sessions that have not been signed out" when I check the "Last account activity" link
- I know there is an option to go to "Security" and from there to each individual Session / Device, and sign-out of it, however, I always do sign-out of my Gmail account, and regularly change my passwords, I would have thought that would sign me out of all other sessions.
- I regularly change my password, but it makes no difference.
- I only ever use my Gmail / Google account on the one solitary device, the same device, I have never used my Gmail account on any other device.
- I always use the Html version of Gmail, though sometimes I did try the new version.
- I have only ever used Gmail as an an individual person, I know that users of Gmail who are groups or companies may have the monthly report option which was definitely previously available to 'individual' users.
- I originally asked this question on security.stackexchange.com - [Gmail - Security - What happened to the option / button that would GENERATE an "Email-Account-Monthly-Activity-Report" for the month?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265480/gmail-security-what-happened-to-the-option-button-that-would-generate-an) ,  but deleted it to not cross-post it with this site.